# How to modify security group rules after ec2 creation terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an ec2 instance with terraform and few steps in cloud-init (like install docker,vim,git etc).
After installation i wish to stop the outbound traffic.

I cannot overwrite the security group and upon adding new securitygroup also didnt help.
any help would be off great use

```
module "airgap_instance" {
  source        = "../../../tf-modules/ec2"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  instance_name = "test_instance"
  sg            = module.airgap_secuirtygroups.sg_id
  user_data     = data.cloudinit_config.cloudconfig.rendered
}
data "cloudinit_config" "cloudconfig" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = true
  part {
    filename     = "install.sh"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = file("${path.module}/scripts/install.sh")
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "wait_for_instance" {
  depends_on = [
    module.airgap_instance.ec2_id
  ]
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/scripts/dep_wait.sh ${module.airgap_instance.ec2_id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_init_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = module.airgap_secuirtygroups.sg_id
  network_interface_id = module.airgap_instance.interface_id
}

resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_final_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = module.airgap_secuirtygroups_update.sg_id
  network_interface_id = module.airgap_instance.interface_id
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.wait_for_instance
  ]
}
```

My security_groups.tf

```
module "airgap_secuirtygroups" {
  source         = "../../../tf-modules/secuirtygroups"
  sg_name        = "terraform-airgap-init-sg"
  sg_description = "terraform-airgap-init-sg-description"
  ingress_ports  = [80, 443]
  egress_ports   = [0]
}

module "airgap_secuirtygroups_update" {
  source         = "../../../tf-modules/secuirtygroups"
  sg_name        = "terraform-airgap-sg"
  sg_description = "terraform-airgap-sg-description"
  ingress_ports  = [80, 443]
  egress_ports   = []
}
```

My modules
ec2.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami                  = var.ami_id
  instance_type        = var.instance_type
  key_name             = var.key_pair_name
  iam_instance_profile = var.instance_profile
  availability_zone    = var.availability_zone
  subnet_id            = var.subnet_id
  security_groups      = ["${var.sg}"]
  user_data            = var.user_data
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.instance_name}"
  }

  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint = "enabled"
    http_tokens   = "required"
  }
}
```

secuirty_groups.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_traffic" {
  name        = var.sg_name
  description = var.sg_description
  vpc_id      = var.sg_vpc_id
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  dynamic "ingress" {
    iterator = port
    for_each = var.ingress_ports
    content {
      from_port   = port.value
      to_port     = port.value
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "egress" {
    iterator = port
    for_each = var.egress_ports
    content {
      from_port   = port.value
      to_port     = port.value
      protocol    = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.sg_name}"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We have no way of knowing because we don't know what the module looks like.

Comment: @MarkoE added them now

Comment: So you want to remove the `egress` part from both SGs? What is the definition for the `egress_ports` variable?

Comment: I wanted to over-write or replace existing ```airgap_secuirtygroups``` with ```airgap_secuirtygroups_update``` my egress is to have outbound all once all the cloud-init thing is done. I wish to revoke all outbound traffic

Comment: Why not change the `airgap_secuirtygroups` to have `egress_ports = []`?

Comment: Yes, that will help but, i want to attach security groups which enable traffic initially. So that , I can install docker, vim ,git all the necessary things. Once the cloud-init takes care of installing all of them i want to cut down the outbound/egress traffic

Comment: Exactly, run it once, when it is complete, just remove any egress ports.

Comment: I was expecting to run one terraform apply and that will take care of 
```1- attaching security group with outbound traffic 
2- install docker and all necessary things 
3- revoke outbound traffic
``` all with one terraform apply

Comment: Well, you can have more than one SG per ENI, so my guess is that both get attached.

Comment: While we can do that it still will have outbound traffic.So, it really didnt help

Comment: No, I wanted to say they both get attached to the same ENI the way you have it implemented currently.